# Error adding elements into ArrayList after intialization

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, graph, collections

I have implemented Graph Data structure using Collections Framework as Adjacency List implementation in Java. I'm not able to add an edge using `addEdge` method defined below. Im getting ArrayList as null. Please help me resolve this issue. Here is my `UndirectedGraph` class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class UndirectedGraph {
    private Map<Vertex, List<Vertex>> adjList;
    public UndirectedGraph() {
        adjList = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Map<Vertex, List<Vertex>> getAdjList() {
        return adjList;
    }

    public List<Vertex> getAdjVertices(int node){
        return adjList.get(new Vertex(node));
    }

    public void addVertex(int node){
        List<Vertex> l = new ArrayList<>();
        Vertex n = new Vertex(node);
        adjList.putIfAbsent(n, l);
    }

    public void removeVertex(int node){
        Vertex v = new Vertex(node);
        adjList.values().forEach(e -> e.remove(v));
        adjList.remove(v);
    }

    public void addEdge(int x, int y){
        Vertex v1 = new Vertex(x);
        Vertex v2 = new Vertex(y);
        List<Vertex> l1 = adjList.get(v1);  // Error here
        List<Vertex> l2 = adjList.get(v2);
        l1.add(v2); // Error here
        l2.add(v1);
    }

    public void removeEdge(int x, int y){
        Vertex v1 = new Vertex(x);
        Vertex v2 = new Vertex(y);
        List<Vertex> l1 = adjList.get(v1);
        List<Vertex> l2 = adjList.get(v2);
        if(l1 != null) l1.remove(v2);
        if(l2 != null) l2.remove(v1);
    }
}
```

Here is my main method call to the graph:

```
UndirectedGraph G = new UndirectedGraph();
G.addVertex(1);
G.addVertex(2);
G.addVertex(3);
G.addVertex(4);
G.addVertex(5);
G.addEdge(1, 2);
G.addEdge(1, 4);
G.addEdge(1, 3);
G.addEdge(1, 5);
G.addEdge(2, 4);
G.addEdge(3, 4);
G.addEdge(4, 5);
System.out.println(G.getAdjList());
```

Error I get is:
[image: Error]

I tried running the main method, which is used to construct the graph. But not able to add the edge, precisely not able to add vertex into ArrayList.